# Angular 13 asynchronous data fetch

Tags: angular, typescript

When displaying tool tip error message in html, I receive the following error:

> "Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.ngtsc(2322)"

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li7iW.jpg)

TypeScript code

```
export class ValidationErrorComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() control!: FormControl;
  @Input() customErrors: ErrorType = {};
  error$: any;

  constructor(public errorStateMatcher: ErrorStateMatcher) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const setError = (ctrl: any) => {
      let errorStr = '';
      Object.entries(ctrl).map(([error, value]: any) => {
        let getError = this.customErrors[error] || FORM_ERRORS[error];
        if (getError != undefined) {
          errorStr += `• ${getError(value)}.\n`;
        }
      });
      return errorStr;
    };

    this.error$ = this.control.statusChanges.pipe(
      tap(console.log),
      startWith({}),
      map((value) => setError(this.control.errors || {}))
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my html code

```html
<mat-icon *ngIf="errorStateMatcher.isErrorState(control, null) && (error$) | async as error " color="warn"
    [matTooltip]=error matTooltipClass="tool-tip">
    error_outline
</mat-icon>
```

Error messages should be displayed asynchronously. Please help to solve this error .

Answer (score 0):

Please create a variable to store the error message which gets set to mat tool tip

ts

```
export class ValidationErrorComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() control!: FormControl;
  @Input() customErrors: ErrorType = {};
  error$: any;
  error : string;

  constructor(public errorStateMatcher: ErrorStateMatcher) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const setError = (ctrl: any) => {
      let errorStr = '';
      Object.entries(ctrl).map(([error, value]: any) => {
        let getError = this.customErrors[error] || FORM_ERRORS[error];
        if (getError != undefined) {
          errorStr += `• ${getError(value)}.\n`;
        }
      });
      return errorStr;
    };

    this.error$ = this.control.statusChanges.pipe(
      startWith({}),
      tap((value) => this.error = setError(this.control.errors || {}))
    );
  }
}
```

html

```
<mat-icon *ngIf="errorStateMatcher.isErrorState(control, null) && error" color="warn" [matTooltip]="error" matTooltipClass="tool-tip">
```

Comment: No its not working, same error .

Comment: @AngadPatil please try now

Comment: No compilation error, but i don't see mandatory validation icon and message on touch/submit.

Comment: @AngadPatil Please share a stackblitz with the issue

Comment: This is working without typescript here , but i need it to be work with typescript.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-error-tooltip-label-5nipja?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-error-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-error-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmy-error%2Fmy-error.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmy-error%2Fmy-error.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the fact your `error` variable in the template is of type `unknown`, while the attribute binding `[matToolTip]` expects a `string`.

Can you try typing your `error$` observable as follows:

```js
export class ValidationErrorComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() control!: FormControl;
  @Input() customErrors: ErrorType = {};
  error$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(public errorStateMatcher: ErrorStateMatcher) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const setError = (ctrl: any) => {
      let errorStr = '';
      Object.entries(ctrl).map(([error, value]: any) => {
        let getError = this.customErrors[error] || FORM_ERRORS[error];
        if (getError != undefined) {
          errorStr += `• ${getError(value)}.\n`;
        }
      });
      return errorStr;
    };

    this.error$ = this.control.statusChanges.pipe(
      tap(console.log),
      startWith({}),
      map((value) => setError(this.control.errors || {}))
    );
  }
}
```

I believe you also have the parentheses incorrectly around your `async` statement in your template. Please update to:

```html
<mat-icon *ngIf="errorStateMatcher.isErrorState(control, null) && (error$ | async as error) " color="warn"
    [matTooltip]=error matTooltipClass="tool-tip">
    error_outline
</mat-icon>
```

Comment: No Luck after changing to this i am getting below error in html .

No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(obj: Observable<string> | Subscribable<string> | Promise<string>): string | null', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'false | Observable<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<string> | Subscribable<string> | Promise<string>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(obj: null | undefined): null', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'false | Observable<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null | undefined'.
  Overload 3 of 3 ...

Comment: Finally it works Thanks for the help.

<mat-icon *ngIf="errorStateMatcher.isErrorState(control, null)  && (error$ | async) ; let error " color="warn"
    [matTooltip]=error matTooltipClass="tool-tip">
    error_outline
</mat-icon>

Comment: Great! Glad your problem was solved